# How can I add a radial gradient effect to particles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas, particles.js

I am creating particle animation using Canvas & JavaScript. in the below example particles are generating and applying colour (red & blue) to each particles dynamically. I want to add Radial Gradient colour effect to each particle. 
I have tried createRadialGradient() method but it make my browser window blank & animation is not working.

How could I achieve this? any reference will be very useful. Thank you in advance.

```js
(function() {
                var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function(callback) {
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                };
                window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
            })();

            var particleArr = [],
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            flakeCount = 700,
            mouseX = -100,
            mouseY = -100,
            xMultiplier = 0.015
            
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            var rate = 0.07788656582264941;

            function getRandomColor() {
                // Random Color Generate
                const colorArr = ["rgba(215,88,69, 1)", "rgba(117, 161, 199, 1)"]; // Blue & Orange Color
                const randomColor = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)];

                return randomColor;
            }

            function flow() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                 
                for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
                    var flake = particleArr[i],
                        x = mouseX,
                        y = mouseY,
                        minDist = 150,
                        x2 = flake.x,
                        y2 = flake.y;

                    var dist = Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y)),
                        dx = x2 - x,
                        dy = y2 - y;
                    
                    if (dist < minDist) {
                        var force = minDist / (dist * dist),
                            xcomp = (x - x2) / dist,
                            ycomp = (y - y2) / dist,
                            deltaV = force / 2;                            
                        flake.velX -= deltaV * xcomp;
                        flake.velY -= deltaV * ycomp;

                    } else {
                        flake.velX *= .98;
                        if (flake.velY <= flake.speed) {
                            flake.velY = flake.speed
                        }
                        flake.velX += Math.cos(flake.step += .05) * flake.stepSize;
                    }
                
                    flake.y += flake.velY;
                    flake.x += flake.velX;                    
                        
                    if (flake.y >= canvas.height || flake.y <= 0) {
                        reset(flake);
                    }

                    if (flake.x >= canvas.width || flake.x <= 0) {
                        reset(flake);
                    }

                    ctx.fillStyle = particleArr[i].color;
                    
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                
                requestAnimationFrame(flow);                
            };

            function reset(flake) {
                let temp = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;
                flake.x = canvas.width;
                flake.y = 50;
                flake.size = 6.692053245649504;
                flake.speed = (Math.random() * 7) + 0.5;
                flake.velY = flake.speed;
                flake.velX = -xMultiplier  * canvas.width * temp;
            }

            function init() {
                for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
                    var x = canvas.width,
                        y = 50,
                        size = 6.692053245649504,
                        speed = 0;
                      
                    particleArr.push({
                        speed: speed,
                        velY: speed,
                        velX: -xMultiplier  * canvas.width  * speed,
                        x: x,
                        y: y,
                        size: size,
                        stepSize: (Math.random()) / 30,
                        step: 0,
                        angle: 360,
                        color: getRandomColor()
                    });
                }

                requestAnimationFrame(flow);
            };

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
                mouseX = e.clientX,
                mouseY = e.clientY     
            });

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            function onWindowResize() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            }

            init();
```

```css
canvas{
                background-color: #000000 !important;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
```

```html
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `fillStyle` to the gradient you created, and don't forget to add color stops:

```
let grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(flake.x, flake.y, 0, flake.x, flake.y, flake.size);
grad.addColorStop(0, 'blue');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'red');
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
                    
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
```

```js
(function() {
                var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function(callback) {
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                };
                window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
            })();

            var particleArr = [],
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            flakeCount = 700,
            mouseX = -100,
            mouseY = -100,
            xMultiplier = 0.015
            
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            var rate = 0.07788656582264941;

            function getRandomColor() {
                // Random Color Generate
                const colorArr = ["rgba(215,88,69, 1)", "rgba(117, 161, 199, 1)"]; // Blue & Orange Color
                const randomColor = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)];

                return randomColor;
            }

            function flow() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                 
                for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
                    var flake = particleArr[i],
                        x = mouseX,
                        y = mouseY,
                        minDist = 150,
                        x2 = flake.x,
                        y2 = flake.y;

                    var dist = Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y)),
                        dx = x2 - x,
                        dy = y2 - y;
                    
                    if (dist < minDist) {
                        var force = minDist / (dist * dist),
                            xcomp = (x - x2) / dist,
                            ycomp = (y - y2) / dist,
                            deltaV = force / 2;                            
                        flake.velX -= deltaV * xcomp;
                        flake.velY -= deltaV * ycomp;

                    } else {
                        flake.velX *= .98;
                        if (flake.velY <= flake.speed) {
                            flake.velY = flake.speed
                        }
                        flake.velX += Math.cos(flake.step += .05) * flake.stepSize;
                    }
                
                    flake.y += flake.velY;
                    flake.x += flake.velX;                    
                        
                    if (flake.y >= canvas.height || flake.y <= 0) {
                        reset(flake);
                    }

                    if (flake.x >= canvas.width || flake.x <= 0) {
                        reset(flake);
                    }

                    let grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(flake.x, flake.y, 0, flake.x, 
                    flake.y, flake.size);
                    grad.addColorStop(0, 'blue');
                    grad.addColorStop(1, 'red');
                    ctx.fillStyle = grad;
              
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                
                requestAnimationFrame(flow);                
            };

            function reset(flake) {
                let temp = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;
                flake.x = canvas.width;
                flake.y = 50;
                flake.size = 6.692053245649504;
                flake.speed = (Math.random() * 7) + 0.5;
                flake.velY = flake.speed;
                flake.velX = -xMultiplier  * canvas.width * temp;
            }

            function init() {
                for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
                    var x = canvas.width,
                        y = 50,
                        size = 6.692053245649504,
                        speed = 0;
                      
                    particleArr.push({
                        speed: speed,
                        velY: speed,
                        velX: -xMultiplier  * canvas.width  * speed,
                        x: x,
                        y: y,
                        size: size,
                        stepSize: (Math.random()) / 30,
                        step: 0,
                        angle: 360,
                        color: getRandomColor()
                    });
                }

                requestAnimationFrame(flow);
            };

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
                mouseX = e.clientX,
                mouseY = e.clientY     
            });

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            function onWindowResize() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            }

            init();
```

```css
canvas{
                background-color: #000000 !important;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Please note that even thought it looks like two circles on each particle (one red and a smaller blue one on top) there is actually a gradient, and tweaking could fix that bulls-eye look. To prove it change the particle size to something much larger (75+).